# Android Program to send messages

Tags: android

I am developing an Android program where I need to send message to some people. Here I have the phone numbers of the people in my database.
Is there any Android source code to broadcast message to those people.
Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

This is exactly what you need, it helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at using the ACTION_SEND action in an intent, along with the EXTRA_SUBJECT, EXTRA_TEXT and others to send Email or SMS messages (or others, if they are available). Android then looks for possible ways to send your data and presents the user with a choice, if possible.

That's all described in the reference section of the developer site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Answer (score 0):

no yar in android there are some drawback are there in that sending text message is one big problem because at a time u can send a message only 1 person it will not provide recipent option, another problem of android is bluetooth was not connecting and modem was not pair..........